# Movesense Android Showcase App sampling rate not changing

Tags: android, movesense

I started using movesense sensors and got started using the Android Showcase app. However when changing the sampling rate for the accelerometer, for example, in the app and then subscribing to the data, I still get 13hz output file. Is that feature in the showcase app just a placeholder and not implemented or is there something I am missing out on? I am sampling with an LG G4 on Android 6.0 using an OP174 sensor.

For example, setting the sampling rate to 104 Hz, I'm hoping to get about 3000 data points out of the csv file for 30 seconds of sensing but I effectively get around 350 data points. Similarly the deltas are consistent with the base rate of 13 Hz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outputting to CSV file for higher rates than 13 Hz was not written in the app, had to add snippet of code.